# Convert subscript from OpenMath to MathML

Tags: javascript, mathml

I'm working with mathdox, to insert equations in my web page. I have implemented all the symbols and mathematical expressions that I need, to insert them as openmath and convert them in to MathML, except subscript. I know that it's suppose to work like this:

```
<OMOBJ xmlns='http://www.openmath.org/OpenMath' version='2.0' cdbase='http://www.openmath.org/cd'>
<OMA style='sub'>
<OMV name='x'/>
<OMI>2</OMI>
</OMA>
</OMOBJ>
```

should convert to

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <msub>
    <mi>X</mi>
    <mn>2</mn>
  </msub> 
</math>
```

but I cannot find a way to implement it in javascript or find it's existing implementation in mathdox.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this only works in Firefox.  The main tools for the job are [`createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) and [`getElementsByTagNameNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagNameNS).  Additionally, I'm not sure where you get your `openmath` document, but I'm going to be retrieving it via `AJAX`.

So, assuming your file structure is:

```
/root
+-/js
| +-convert.js
|
+-/xml
| +-openmath.xml
|
+-index.html
```

And your files are as follows:

**index.html**

The only thing to note about `index.html` is that we set an `id` on the `<math>` element that we want to put the converted tags under.  We also include the `convert.js` JavaScript file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert</title>
    <script src="js/convert.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" id="target"></math>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

**openmath.xml**

This file is just the XML that you posted in your question that we will be converting to the math namespace.

```
<OMOBJ xmlns='http://www.openmath.org/OpenMath' version='2.0' cdbase='http://www.openmath.org/cd'>
    <OMA style='sub'>
        <OMV name='x' />
        <OMI>2</OMI>
    </OMA>
</OMOBJ>
```

**convert.js**

The way that `convert.js` works is that it loads up the openmath document over xhr, then creates a new XML document with the document text using `DOMParser()` and `parseFromString()`.  Then we feed that document to `mathSubscriptConverter()` which pulls all the `OMA` tags, gets the relevant data from them, and then converts them to `msub` tags.  Once we have the `msub` tags, we add them as children under the `<math>` tag that exists in our `index.html`.

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var mathNS = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML",
        openMathNS = "http://www.openmath.org/OpenMath",
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    function mathSubscriptConverter(openmathDoc) {
        var target = document.getElementById("target"),
            omas = openmathDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS(openMathNS, "OMA");

        // Make sure we have a math element to put this under
        if (target) {
            // Iterate each OMA tag
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(omas, function (oma) {
                var omv, omi, msub, mi, mn;

                // Get the first OMV
                omv = oma.getElementsByTagNameNS(openMathNS, "OMV")[0];
                // Get the first OMV
                omi = oma.getElementsByTagNameNS(openMathNS, "OMI")[0];

                // Create a subscript tag in the math namespace
                msub = document.createElementNS(mathNS, "msub");
                // Create an mi tag in the math namespace
                mi = document.createElementNS(mathNS, "mi");
                // Create an mn tag in the math namespace
                mn = document.createElementNS(mathNS, "mn");

                // Set our math attributes
                mi.innerHTML = omv.getAttribute("name");
                mn.innerHTML = omi.innerHTML;

                // Add our new elements to the target
                msub.appendChild(mi);
                msub.appendChild(mn);
                target.appendChild(msub);
            });
        }
    }

    // Wait for document load
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        // Load our openmath document
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var parser = new DOMParser(),
                    mdoc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "application/xml");
                mathSubscriptConverter(mdoc);
            }
        };
        xhr.open("GET", "xml/openmath.xml", true);
        xhr.send();
    });

}());
```